# Python Flask Blueprints - Defining API Docs for multiple endpoints in one .yaml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flasgger

I have some endpoints in one of my blueprints, and I'm hoping to add all the API documentation for this blueprint into a single `.yaml` file. However, with my current `.yaml` file structure and blueprint code, it seems like flasgger is not recognizing the correct definition.

Blueprint code:

```
app_obj = Flask(name)
app_obj.register_blueprint(user_controller, url_prefix="/")
# ...

user_controller = Blueprint("controllers/user_controller", __name__)

@user_controller.route('/signup', endpoint='signup', methods=['POST'])
@swag_from('user.yml', endpoint=f'{user_controller.name}.signup')
def signup():
    response = RestResponse()
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = request.get_json()
            newly_created_user = UserService.create_user(data.get("username"), data.get("email"),
                                                         data.get("password"), data.get("name"))
            response.data = newly_created_user
        return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    except BadRequest as err:
        response.data = GenericException(message=err.description).to_dict()
        return jsonify(response.to_dict()), err.code
```

As for my *user.yaml*:

```
definitions:
  User:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string
      username:
        type: string
      email:
        type: string
      created_at:
        type: string
      updated_at:
        type: string

paths:
  "/signup":
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: body
          type: string
          required: true
        - name: username
          in: body
          type: string
          required: true
        - name: password
          in: body
          type: string
          required: true
        - email: email
          in: body
          type: string
          required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: Newly created user
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
```

This is what */apidocs* looks like for me: [image]

Appreciate all the help i can get. Thanks!

Comment: Not an official answer, but it seems like with @swag_from() we cannot do this, because it directly looks for 'parameters', skipping over paths & methods.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want but a way to keep your specs on a single file is to define the *template_file* arg on the Swagger instance. The *template_file* indicates the full path of the spec file. For instance, if you have defined an [application factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/factory/#the-application-factory), I'm quite sure that you'll be able to achieve something with the following example:

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flasgger import Swagger

def create_app():
    """create_app function."""
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.shell_context_processor
    def _shell_context():
        return {"app": app}

    swagger = Swagger(app, template_file='my_spec.yaml')

    with app.app_context():
        app.register_blueprint(my_route)

    return app
```

Noticed the *template_file* argument? You must provide the full path of the spec file an it must be an *yaml* file. You can use the following as an example:

**my_spec.yaml**

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'

################################################################################
#                              API Information                                 #
################################################################################
info:
  version: '1.0.0'
  title: My Api Swagger
  description: |
    This tests many paths for my swagger

################################################################################
#                  Host, Base Path, Schemes and Content Types                  #
################################################################################
# The host (name or ip) serving the API
host: localhost:3000

# The base path on which the API is served, relative to the host. Will be prefixed to all paths. Used to control versioning
basePath: /v1/

# The transfer protocol of the API
schemes:
  - http
# Format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# Format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json

################################################################################
#                                    Paths                                     #
################################################################################
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      summary: Test 1
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: request
          description: request
          required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
  /test2:
    get:
      summary: Test 2
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: request
          description: request
          required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A User object
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          description: The user ID.
        username:
          type: string
          description: The user name.
```

With that, all of your configuration will rely on one single file. You don't even have to use *swag_from()* on every endpoint.

Important to inform that the default uri to access *Flasgger* is:

`/apidocs/#/`

So in our example above, to access the swagger you'll use:

http://localhost:3000/apidocs/#/

#### Other resources

- One single file spec example from *Flasgger* itself:

  https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger/blob/master/examples/test_refs.py
- How to change the default configuration of swagger on flasgger:

  https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger#customize-default-configurations
- Swagger docs to create your templates:

  https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/basic-structure/